# How do I find the closed form of this integral?

Tags: integration, gamma-function

I was trying to calculate the expected value of $\log(Y)$ where $Y$ has gamma distribution and I got to something like this:

$$\int_0^\infty \log(z)z^{\phi-1}e^{-z} \, dz,$$ wich based on other results should give me $\Gamma'(\phi)$ but I have no idea how to solve the integral, what are the steps to get the answer?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function , and see also http://129.81.170.14/~vhm/formula_html/final10.pdf for a pile of proofs of related results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you already know the answer. Since:
$$ \Gamma(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}\,dx \tag{1}$$
by differentiating (with respect to $\alpha$) under the integral sign we get:
$$ \frac{d}{d\alpha}\Gamma(\alpha) = \int_{0}^{+\infty} x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}\log x\,dx\tag{2}$$
and since $$\frac{\Gamma'(\alpha)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}=\frac{d}{d\alpha}\log\Gamma(\alpha) = \psi(\alpha) = H_{\alpha-1}-\gamma, \tag{3}$$

where $H_n$ stands for the $n$-th [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), $\psi(z)$ for the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) and $\gamma$ for the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), we have:

> $$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}\log x\,dx = \Gamma'(\alpha) = \left(H_{\alpha-1}-\gamma\right)\Gamma(\alpha).\tag{4}$$